# How to get filtering params for jquery datatable(datatables.net)?

Tags: datatables

I'm using jquery DataTables (from datatables.net) with server-side processing and ColumnFiltering add-on. I need to add a callback which will compute subtotals based on filtered data. In order to achieve this I want to make a separate ajax call. How can I  extract the current  ajax parameters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assign datatable object to a var on creation, for example:

```
var oTable = $("selector").dataTable({...});`
```

Later use this:

```
var params = oTable.oApi._fnAjaxParameters(oTable.dataTable().fnSettings());
```

it returns all ajax parameters which would be sent in a normal data loading request for datatables. Make your ajax call like this :

```
$.post("url",$.param(params),function(response){....});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using DataTables 1.10 (the current version as of this answer), this is now a lot easier to access with the ajax.params() method.

Example from http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.params()

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: "data.json",
    serverSide: true
} );

table.on( 'xhr', function () {
    var data = table.ajax.params();
    alert( 'Search term was: '+data.search.value );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it looks like you might want the ajax ordering parameters as well. The code below assumes you have a datatable called 'your_table'.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "your_url",
   data: {         
       orderColumn: your_table.ajax.params().order[0]['column'],
       orderDirection: your_table.ajax.params().order[0]['dir'],
       searchText: your_table.ajax.params().search.value
   }
});
```

Thank you MrDerp for your response - helped me with my own table! I had difficulty finding the other parameters so I thought I would share here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table.on( 'xhr', function () {
            var data = table.ajax.params();
            var filter_values = [];

            //suppose you have 10 columns in your datatable
            for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                search_value = "sSearch_"+i;
                filter_values.push(data[search_value])
            }
            console.log(filter_values);
        });
```